# Is Dave really mad at me?

Tags: steganography

I am Patrick. Tonight, I got a mail from my old friend Dave. He was out of town for a while, and got back today.

Well, we had an argument on the phone yesterday, and I think he had hard feelings. I was supposed to pick him up from the airport after he gave me a phone call, but he never called.

Then, I got this strange looking mail. What do you think? Is he really mad at me?

> Dear patrick, how are you? i feeL really hAppy being back home!
>
> We should MEet as soon as possible. i bet that my timE here will be very EnjOyaBle. 
>   hopefully, i will be free some time at Five pm tomorrow.
>
> how about a couple of beers after Work? maybe there wIll be a happy
>   hour, and we caN driNk cheap beers :)
>
> by the way, I might have soUnded like a douche today when we were
>   talking on the Phone. i must apologize about what i havE said. i
>   could havE been more Understanding about your situation. but you must
>   also admit that you are being too much sensitive after bReaking up
>   with your girlfriend.
>
> we are old friends, mate! we have overcome so Many problems, aNd we
>   can trash this out like We did all the time.
>
> see you tomorrow,
>   dave.

**Edit:** I have mistyped two letters and I have corrected them now. Sorry.

Hint 1:

> How do you read a sentence?

Hint 2:

> What do you use a flashlight for?

Comment: I think Dave's drunk.

Comment: Is Dave the type of person who normally capitalizes `I` (or his sentences, for that matter)?

Comment: Your read a sentence left to right.

Comment: @Deadric that is correct. More hints to come

Comment: We use a flashlight to see in the darkness?

Comment: Very clever puzzle. Good work.

Comment: "We should MEet" should be "we should MEet"

Comment: What is up with the flashlight hint?  Did I miss something?

Comment: @zipzit you use a flashlight to see in front of you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How I solved it:

> Look at the capital letters and use their position in the word to identify which letter you need from the following word.
>
>  "`Dear patrick`":  `D` is in the first position in `Dear`, so we take the first letter from `patrick`: **`P`**
>  "`EnjOyaBle`":  We take the 1st, 4th, and 7th letters from the following word (`hopefully`): **`HEL`**

He actually is telling you

> Please help me; I am kidnapped!

Comment: indeed, that is true. congrats!

Comment: @cagirici I think you still have two wrong letters in the text (wrong as in not right for the trick used) the first letters of the second and fourth paragraph should be small letters just like in the third and fifth

Comment: but is dave really mad at him?

Comment: You know, we really only have Patrick's side of the story here. How do we know he's not responsible for Dave's current state?

Comment: @gentlePurpleRain, great edit improving the readability, thanks