# What happened to Dave?

Tags: steganography

After I have figured out if [Dave was really mad at me](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25809/is-dave-really-mad-at-me),

> I panicked and called the police.

After a couple of minutes, I saw a strange post of mine. Well, I was not on StackExchange! It was written by Dave. But why would he log in my account and write his message as a post, instead of sending me another email?

> Hello again, Patrick! I am sorry for what I 
>        did.
>   I was just so mad at you and wanted to make you struggle with some meaningless
>        email. 
>   I just made random letters uppercase.
>        Please 
>   do not take any messages from that mail.
>
> Maybe we can still hang
>        out, 
>   what do you say?
>        Take 
>   your time to answer. I
>        understand 
>   if you say
>        no 
>   after that gibberish mail of mine.
>
> I have some news about
>        Daniel 
>   by the way. He called me last week. He was looking for a PhD position in MIT. I don't think he will never,
>        ever
>   get a position. He is lazy, you know. When I tell this to him, he gets angry. Maybe he will 
>        reason 
>   with me after a time. 
>        Considering 
>   that he has ups 
>        and 
>   downs 
>        sometimes, 
>   he probably cannot just take
>        it 
>   easy right now.
>
> Whatever.
>        Now,
>   I am going to rest. Drink some coffee and watch TV. Ah, by the way, my cellphone is broken. I dropped it. Therefore, it is off. If you want to hang
>        out,
>   just send me an e-mail.
>
> Best,
>   Dave.

Should I

> call the police back and

explain that everything was a misunderstanding?

**Hint:**

> Hint is in the question itself. Why write as a post instead of sending an e-mail?

Comment: better safe than sorry, don't :D

Comment: the biggest question for me is, how does he know your password?! :o

Comment: @sjaakbakker He is a very close friend of mine, he must have figured out :p

Comment: i see so many things, but none jump out as the certain truth.

Comment: Saw the words, but can't get to anything with it. :(

Comment: @sjaakbakker I will continue giving hints after a couple of hours. The second hint will lead you directly to the answer, try harder to solve it with the first hint :)

Comment: I believe a post like that would get deleted very quickly pretty much anywhere on StackExchange.

Comment: @GOTO0 why would you think that? There are many sandboxes all over :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the secret message hidden in the post is

> **DEPOT UNDER CASINO**

**Explanation As Below.**

> In the edit mode, these words seems to be separated out

The words

> did 
> email 
> please 
> out 
> take 
> understand 
> no 
> daniel 
> ever 
> reason 
> considering 
> and 
> sometimes 
> it 
> now 
> out

**Then**

> Take the first letters

**And it will form**

> DEPOT UNDER CASINO (DEPOTUNDERCASINO)

So I think

> you should check the depot under the casino before calling the cops.

Comment: You got somewhere with the hints, mate :)

Comment: i am really curious how you got to this :)

Comment: :) I will try finding out the remaining

Comment: @sjaak I have updated my answer. Please check now.

Comment: ooo...that is really clever of @cagirici

Comment: do you check that mode for every question?

Comment: Not really. I checked it because the hint was "Why write as a post instead of sending an e-mail"

Comment: In stackexchange editor we can add hidden messages (messages that are not visible in the post, but only in the editor), and I was looking for it. Then I noticed this pattern.

Comment: i still don't see the pattern, but good interpretation of the the hint

Comment: In the edit mode, you can see that these words are singled out in separate  lines from the rest of the words in the sentences.

Comment: im pretty new here, I didn't know that mode, i was looking at the edits that were made. But now i see! very clever

Answer (score -2):

May be the kidnapper wants you to suspect Daniel in future, So MR.kidnapper asks Dave to logon your account and write a post , So you will believe that it is actually Dave an no one else