# Message from your best friend

Tags: steganography

You got a ridiculous message from your best friend that doesn't make sense. But you know that it must be important because he is a wise man, so you must find out what he is trying to tell.

```
Mr. Robin was a person who could fly.

Baited by a voice, he started floating.

Flying in the skies, he saw something weird.

Birds without wings were floating in the air.

Actually there were no birds at all.

Betrayal of his own mind was the fact.
```

Comment: why is this tagged steganography?

Comment: because there is a secret word in the message. like in this example there is a different pattern: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25809/is-dave-really-mad-at-me if the tag is wrong, just point the correct one instead of a downvote. thanks

Comment: I didn't downvote. I didn't even point out the tag was wrong. I just wanted to know if you had deliberately and knowingly chosen it and I could use that as a clue

Comment: After all those "without reason" downvotes, I lost my faith in this community that I loved in this short amount of time. Will get myself away from asking questions till I find some reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The first letter from the first line, second letter from the second line, and so on spell out `Mayday`. It sounds like he's in serious trouble.

Comment: Well done that is correct :)